# Python matplotlib draws curve outside axis by default?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis

Does Python matplotlib by default plot outside the axis if `matplotlib.pyplot.xlim` is applied?

This is the code I have written.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure()
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 11)
y = x**2
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlim((-5, 5))
```

This is what I get: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTHTV.png)

This is what I want:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgG6T.png)

I am using matplotlib version 3.5.3 with Spyder IDE.

Comment: My guess is it's a Spyder bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated Spyder from 5.1.5 to 5.3.3 by

```
conda uninstall spyder
conda install spyder=5.3.3
```

Now Spyder does not plot across the axes anymore.

edit:
I was wrong! The problem still occurs. I could find out that the Spyder IPython console format option causes the error. By default "PNG" is set. I typically use "SVG". That is why I first thought the update fixed the issue.
[image]

When I choose "SVG" lines still are drawn outside the axis. I executed

```
plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]), plt.xlim((2, 3))
```

[image]
However, when I choose "PNG" everything works fine.

I will ignore this bug, because when I choose "SVG", execute

```
plt.savefig("myfig.pdf")
```

and then open the file, all lines are within the box.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by updating all libs in anaconda by :

```
conda update --all
```

and disabling inline graphics generation in Spyder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like 'clip_on' is setted to 'False'.

Try to set it to 'True' when you plot:

```
plt.plot(x, y, clip_on = True)
```

Another option is to clip your x and y before plotting:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.figure()
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 11)
y = x**2
mask = np.logical_and(np.less_equal(x,5), np.greater_equal(x,-5))
new_x = x[mask]
new_y = y[mask]
plt.plot(new_x, new_y, clip_on=False) #clip_on=False just for demonstration
plt.xlim((-5, 5))
```

Thats way, eventhough 'clip_on' is setted to 'False', there won't be data outside your grid.

[matplotlib documentation for 'clip_on'.](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_clip_on.html)